# NodeJS, can't find css, js when using friendly url

Tags: node.js

this is my first question on stackoverflow, and my english so bad, sorry about that.

In nodejs application, when i using url like "/post_detail?id=123"

```
app.get('/post_detail', function(req, res) {
    res.render("post_detail", {id: req.param("id")})
});
```

It's ok, i will load all js and css in post_detail page:

```
GET /css/main.css 304 7.194 ms - -
GET /css/themes.css 304 7.313 ms - -
GET /js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js 304 8.139 ms - -
GET /js/plugins.js 304 8.810 ms - -
GET /js/app.js 304 16.648 ms - -
```

But, when i using "/post_detai/123" and router:

```
app.get('/post_detail/:id', function(req, res) {
    res.render("post_detail", {id: req.param("id")})
});
```

In console gives the below errors:

```
GET /post_detail/css/themes.css 404 38.535 ms - 965
GET /post_detail/css/main.css 404 38.817 ms - 965
GET /post_detail/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js 404 28.060 ms - 965
GET /post_detail/js/plugins.js 404 19.449 ms - 965
GET /post_detail/js/app.js 404 16.454 ms - 965
```

So, how to solve this problem? Please help me. :(

Thanks for your help.

P/S: when i'm using url "/post_detail/123", in console is there any difference:
Url "/post_detail?id=123"

```
GET /css/themes.css 304 7.313 ms - -
```

Url "/post_detail/123"

```
GET /post_detail/css/themes.css 404 38.535 ms - 965
```

Comment: Did you try `req.params.id`?

Comment: Yes, i'll try, but nothing else. :(

Comment: Are you using the `express.static()` middleware (preferrably near the top of your middleware/route stack)? If so, are you passing the correct path to it?

Comment: Yes, i'm using express.static() in app.js. Is there any difference when using url "post_detail/123", in console. I've added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are most likely using relative paths rather than absolute paths when including your `js` and `css` files.

In your view file (perhaps `layout.html`, I'm only guessing at the structure of your project) try using urls prefixed with a forward slash:

```
<!-- This -->
<link href="/css/main.css">
<script src="/js/app.js"></script> 

<!-- Rather than this -->
<link href="css/main.css">
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

When you are on `/post_detail?id=123` the relative paths work properly, since they are relative to `/` but when you visit `/post_detail/123` they are now relative to `/post_detail/` and will request the resources with a prefixed `/post_detail/`.

So try and use absolute paths in your view and I hope it works.

Comment: So, i'm not using <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">. I'm using <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">, but nothing else. :(

Comment: @SiêuuNhânnConnNítt You should use absolute paths, otherwise the browser will base the asset path relative to the current path/route in the browser. That's why you're seeing requests for `/post_detail/css/themes.css`.

Comment: @mscdex Oh, i'll try again, i also think so, but I do not know what to do. :| If i solve problem, i'll post up. Thanks everyone. :D

Comment: @SiêuuNhânnConnNítt try adding the forward slash before the url and let us know if it works.